# output String is different in APEX and JS

Tags: apex, javascript

I'm trying to create a small `base64` string in Apex and here is my sample code.

```
public void getjwt(){
        String header = '{ "alg": "HS256", "typ": "JWT" }';
        String token = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header));
        System.debug(token);
    }

     public String base64URLencode(Blob input){ 
        String output = encodingUtil.base64Encode(input);
        output = output.replace('+', '-');
        output = output.replace('/', '_');
        while ( output.endsWith('=')){
            output = output.subString(0,output.length()-1);
        }
        return output;
    }
```

when I run this program, the output that I get is `eyAiYWxnIjogIkhTMjU2IiwgInR5cCI6ICJKV1QiIH0`

I've got a similar code in javascript and the code is as below.

```
function generateJWT() {
  header = {
    "alg": "HS256",
    "typ": "JWT"
  };
  var token = base64url(JSON.stringify(header));;
  console.log(token)
}


function base64url(input) {
  var base64String = btoa(input);
  return urlConvertBase64(base64String);
}

function urlConvertBase64(input) {
  var output = input.replace(/=+$/, '');
  output = output.replace(/\+/g, '-');
  output = output.replace(/\//g, '_');

  return output;
}
```

when I run this js. The output I get is `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9`. Here is the  live fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6q2vsy3r/

Why aren't both the outputs the same? Am I doing something wrong?

Please let me know how can I fix this.

Comment: Are there whitespace differences that could be causing the input to the encoding to be different in the two cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is whitespace difference. Your apex assumes the JSON is:

```
{ "alg": "HS256", "typ": "JWT" }
```

Yet your JS `JSON.stringify` generates:

```
{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}
```

Comment: I feel like hanging myself. Lol. Thanks, Mate. This worked